# How to schedule a backup in Plesk for Database and configuration?

Tags: backup, ftp, scheduled-task, database-backup

I like to make a scheduled backup in plesk 10.4.
My target is to

1. Take the backup of Database and configuration and put in the FTP
   location.  I dont see any option in backup manager in plesk.  Any
   help is greatly appreciated.
2. Then there is a setting "Suspend domain
   until backup task is completed"  If I uncheck will that be a
   problem?
3. Is that a way to get backup of specific database of a domain in plesk?.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take the backup of Database and configuration and put in the FTP
>   location. I dont see any option in backup manager in plesk.

You can not take a scheduled backup of databases alone on a Plesk Server separate from the domain content merely using the control panel or even the `pleskbackup` cli tool.

You'll need to use mysql tools to dump specific databases and then schedule cron jobs to your liking.

> Then there is a setting "Suspend domain until backup task is
>   completed" If I uncheck will that be a problem?

The problem is that the hosting account tenants can log in and modify files as their files are being backed up. This has the potential to cause funny things if a person is actively modifying files in the same time span as a backup. Imagine if index.html is backed up, and subpage.html is edited before being backed up. Then the user goes and performs an edit on index.html. If a restore is performed, index.html will be "old" but subpage.html will be "new." It will simply be confusing, but no true data loss will be sustained.

Suspending the domain makes it impossible for the user to log in and change their files for the duration of the backup.

> Is that a way to get backup of specific database of a domain in
>   plesk?.

No, you will have to use mysqldump, or a third party tool to get a backup of a specific domain.

I've hit my head against many walls trying to get Plesk 10 to backup servers with any amount of reasonable flexibility. Simply put, it has terrible built-in tools that limit a server administrator's ability to protect customers. The only solution I've found is hacking together my own scripts and using third-party plugins.

Comment: Thank you very much..  I got a very good information from you..  So in order to achieve the backup configuration and database I have to write my own cron job...  I will try that..Do yo know any plesk addon which I can buy and achieve this functionality or  can I have plesk as a repository and copy only the modified files.. is tat possible.. Once again thank you very much for your quick answer..

Comment: There are some plesk backup plugins out there. I like [the one from 4PSA](http://www.4psa.com/products-4psatbackup.html) but haven't bought it yet. [R1Soft makes one as well](http://www.r1soft.com/linux-cdp/cdp-enterprise-edition/panels/). There's also [Acronis TrueImage for plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/partners/).